# Determine if the given property is a Navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am writing a code to map certain properties from one object to another except the **Navigational** properties.

My code looks something like this:

```
var properties = typeof(TOne).GetProperties();

var t = new TOne();
foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    var skip = exempt == null || (exempt != null && exempt.Contains(prop.Name));

    if (!skip &&  CommonHelper.HasProperty(obj, prop.Name))
    {           
        var _prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);                    
        CommonHelper.SetPropValue(t, prop.Name, _prop.GetValue(obj, null));                    
    }
}
```

I would like to skip all the navigational properties (do not wish to copy object but primitive types).

For example:

```
class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DetailId")]
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }

    public int DetailId { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to copy **DetailId** but not the **Detail** object.

Comment: Automapper is your friend (https://automapper.org). nobody bothers to write this kind of copy code anymore in my experience

Comment: Hi JohnB, thanks for your suggestion but I would like to learn to write one myself.

Comment: Is EF context metadata accessible for your mapper? If so, what EF version do you use (metadata were changed from v6 to v7)?.

Comment: EF context metadata is accessible and I am using EF v6.

Comment: Have you looked at doing something like this using Type.IsPrimitive? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442534/how-to-test-if-type-is-primitive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Eric H**.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664428/4694659) would work for me where we compare the type of the value of the property. Here, we are checking whether the type of value of the property is **Object**:

```
object valueOfProperty = ...
if(Convert.GetTypeCode(valueOfProperty) != TypeCode.Object){
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

You should have defined your property `Detail` as a virtual property. After all, it is not a real Detail item in your tables.

Once you've declared all relational properties virtual, you'll only have to process the non-virtual properties.

See [How to find out whether a property is virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243541/find-out-if-a-property-is-declared-virtual)

Comment: Thanks Harald, I just gave an example to explain my scenario. In real world I do decorate those properties with virtual.